# Chrome 91 Devtools Inspector inapplicable CSS class no longer grayed out

Tags: css, google-chrome-devtools

Given the following HTML...

```
<div class="first">FIRST</div>
<div class="second">SECOND</div>
```

... and the following CSS...

```
.first, .second {
    background: red;
}
```

When I used to inspect just the first DIV, I'm sure Chrome 91 Devtools used to gray out the inapplicable class (`.second`). However, this is no longer happening. See here:

[image]

Does anyone know how I can turn this feature on again or if there is a place where the color of elements in the inspector can be customized? Here's a [CodePen of the above code](https://codepen.io/clayrav/pen/xxdwoba).

Comment: No answers. Serves me right for asking the question on a weekend.